# Frame.Navigate and Garbage collection

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I have a `Frame` object and 2 hyperlinks. Each hyperlink when clicked will navigate the frame to a different `Page` object.

The frame is navigated with `Frame.Navigate(new Page1());`.

If the user switches between the 2 pages many times, the pages remain in memory, so after viewing page1 10 times and page2 also 10 times, all 20 pages will remain in memory.

What is the correct way of navigating in a WPF application so that I can avoid such issues?

**EDIT**

I have also tried manual garbage collection every time the frame is navigated, I used this code:

```
void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect();
    Debug.WriteLine("Garbage Collected");
}
```

This did not resolve the problem.

Comment: is it possible to cache your instances of the 2 pages and then use `Frame.Navigate(GetPage1())` where GetPage1() is a function that will either return the cached Page1 instance, or create a new instance of Page1 and cache it. Then do a similar thing for Page2. I don't know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: [MSDN explaining page lifetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#PageLifetime)

Comment: You need to Keepalive and use NavigationService.Navigate() so the pages are in the journal;